# In EF 4.1 code first my unit test runner doesn't have a connection string but my tests pass

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am using EF 4.1 code first with SQLCE 4.0
When I run a unit test to create and retrieve a record... the test passes!

But no database file is created.

I'm guessing the test runner has no connection string configured so... what happens? does it assume  I want an in memory database? what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify connection string this one will be used:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=YourContextName; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

So your database is created in your SQLExpress instance.